# How to auto-generate mesh from .step file using GMSH or similar?

Tags: python, mesh, cad, finite-element-analysis, freecad

I need to produce simulation data for randomly generated cantilever beams, and save their maximum deflection given a load, and/or perform frequency-response analysis. To do this the body needs to be meshed as an FEM mesh. Hence, I would like to write a script that generates a mesh file (.msh) from that single-body .step file.

Desired Pipeline:
Input: single-body .step file of a cantilever beam with an arbitrary cross-section
Output: .msh file of the meshed body

Comment: I found a way using <http://onelab.info/pipermail/gmsh/2015/010190.html>. However, I realized that this is only half of my problem. Now I have to figure out how to automate the CalculiX analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution below:

```
Merge "test.step";

Mesh.Algorithm3D = 1;
// 1=Delaunay, 4=Frontal, 5=Frontal Delaunay, 6=Frontal Hex, 7=MMG3D, 9=R-tree
// default = 1

//Mesh  2;  // surface
Mesh  3;  // volume

Mesh.Format = 2;
// 1=msh, 2=unv, 10=automatic, 19=vrml, 27=stl, 30=mesh, 31=bdf, 32=cgns, 33=med, 40=ply2
// default = 10

Mesh.SaveAll = 1;
// Ignore Physical definitions and save all elements

Save "mymesh.msh";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `gmsh` for this.

Use the CalculiX pre- and postprocessor `cgx` to generate the geometry and the mesh. It can relatively easily generate second order hex elements which yield very good results with relatively few elements.